# Database design for multiple tenant application

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am building a web application where we have the concept of `groups`.
A group can be roughly thought of like a Facebook group where you have a number of people attached to it.
The DB for the app is going to be Postgres.
Ideally, all data relating to a group would be independent of others and hence a need to isolate all tables pertaining to a `group`.
What is the right way to do it so that we can scale, backup easily as usage grows?
Should we have one DB per `group` OR one schema per `group`?

Comment: You could call "groups" in the above case "manbearpigs" and it would tell us nothing more of the concept you're trying to implement. How about telling us what you mean by a "concept of a groups" and what you're doing in the app or business?

Comment: added more info

Answer (score 3):

> A group can be roughly thought of like a Facebook group where you have a number of people attached to it.

There is nothing about a Facebook Group that in any fashion requires a new a database, schema, nor table; and, there is nothing to be gained by the added complexity. All groups on Facebook have the same capabilities. They have the same meta-data. They're for the same-type of thing "Facebook Users." There all accessed through the same endpoints on their graph API, and they're all rendered with the CSS, and HTML.

Comment: alright if its still not clear let's draw another analogy.
let's say a `college/school` can be a group and each college would have many entities(which I want to map as tables) like teachers/students/staffs etc.
Now the schema is the same for all such colleges but for each college, I want to store data in isolation.

Comment: That still wouldn't be another database, you'd have table for `institutions` and likely another one for `staff` and `students` or whatever (or even have that combined too)

Comment: so for each college should i have a schema?
e.g institution_cornell, institution_stanford

Comment: No... Schemas are to separate discrete *concepts* of a database, not different *values* or sets of values. For example, admission, cafeteria, and accounting could be different *schemas*.